# Websphere Remote Debugging: Connection failing from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, websphere, redhat, remote-debugging

I am trying to connect remotely to a WAS 8.5 instance running on RHEL 6 from my Eclipse desktop on Windows. However I'm having no luck and I can't see any errors on the server side. The only error I see is on Eclipse which basically says the connection couldn't be made and to check securiy settings if Security as been enabled.

> The connection failed after trying to use all the available connection
>   types.
>
> Verify the port values are correct and the server has been started. If
>   the security of the server is enabled, verify the "Security is enabled
>   on this server" check box is selected, and the user ID and password
>   are provided. You can specify this in the server editor or when
>   creating a new server.
>
> For a Technote with details on the most common server connection
>   problem, see http://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21266028.
>
> The last connection attempt failed with the following exception:
>   ADMC0016E: The system cannot create a SOAP connector to connect to
>   host [remote server] at port xxxx.

Is there any logs I can turn on? I can see the request coming from my desktop machine on RHEL host but it seems  either WAS is not getting it or something is failing or not set right in WAS. I am using WAS 8.5.5.1 runtimes on my desktop and WAS 8.5.5.9 on RHEL host.

Thanks

Comment: First check if you dont have any firewall that blocks the trafic. Use telnet or different tool to validate that you have connectivity on the specified port. Second you can try to run Eclipse with IBM JVM provided with WAS that you have installed on your desktop.